# Manifest merge failed : when using kotlin module

Tags: android, android-manifest, kotlin, android-module

I have android studio **module "domain"**  which has kotlin files.
I tried to using it `as library` for my **app module** like this.

```
 compile project(':domain')
```

I get merge conflict error

Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: First check the Gradle Console. Often there's more info in that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @windrider I saw the gradle console.

**Problem** : **2 manifest files**

1. App module
2. Domain Module ( domain was also a android module)

The conflict was due to

`android:label="@string/app_name"`     **in both modules** as there were **2 label for same app**.

**Solution :**

Delete    `android:label="@string/app_name"`  from **domain module manifest file's Application block** and **rebuild** .